# How to apply parent's parent width to relative positioned child div?

Tags: html, css

i created a small example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdoLw0yu/17/)

When hovering over one of the red boxes i want the text to fill the complete 'row's' width, starting from the left border of the parent div and looking the same for all the boxes.

the text-height should later be animated

(edit: to clarify, each .ma-text should have the width of .contentaround, the first of each row already has the correct width and position)

```css
.contentaround{
  max-width: 80%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.ma{
  min-height: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width:23%;
}

.ma-text{
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 65vw;
  max-width: 1050px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
}
.ma:hover .ma-text{
  height: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentaround">
  <div class="ma ">
  <div class="ma-icon">x</div>
  <div class="ma-text">
    <p>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="ma ">
  <div class="ma-icon">x</div>
  <div class="ma-text">
    <p>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="ma ">
  <div class="ma-icon">x</div>
  <div class="ma-text">
    <p>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="ma ">
  <div class="ma-icon">x</div>
  <div class="ma-text">
    <p>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ma ">
  <div class="ma-icon">x</div>
  <div class="ma-text">
    <p>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the parent element has a relative position, the child element need only have width: 100% to have the width of the parent element.

```css
.contentaround{
  max-width: 80%;
}
.ma{
  min-height: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width:23%;
}

.ma-text{
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 65vw;
  max-width: 1050px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
}
.ma:hover .ma-text{
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentaround">
  <div class="ma ">
  <div class="ma-icon">x</div>
  <div class="ma-text">
    <p>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ma ">
  <div class="ma-icon">x</div>
  <div class="ma-text">
    <p>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vdoLw0yu/25/

Comment: the texts should fill the width of .contentaround, creating a temporary row